# How to Hide a dynamic folder in URL with yii?

Tags: php, url, dynamic, yii, seo

We are creating an application where we are able to create pages inside our DB. All of our domains are going to point to this application, so we are storing our domains also in the DB. Also based on that domain we are creating new layouts and determining what pages belong to that domain. With that being said here is our issue:

We put a rule inside the urlMangaer:
`'http://dev.<domain:\w+>.com'=>'site/view'`
which outputs: `http://dev.example.com/example/index`
 which represents: `http://dev.$domain.com/$domain/$page`

Our goal is for the url to read `http://dev.$domain.com/$page` and still have the functionality we need.

Here is our action call:
 `public function actionView($domain = null,$page = null, $parm = null){}`

A possible solution we thought of is extending the urlManager but we don't know where to begin to do so.

Comment: Not sure about what I'm saying but can't you do it in the apache .htaccess file?

Comment: We thought about that and saw we would be unable to do it through the .htaccess file.

Comment: So the domain portion of the URL needs to change depending on what domain the user accessed the application from, but there is only going to be one instance of the application?

Comment: correct that's what we need, right now we have www.example.com/$domain/$page where $domain = example but we need to get rid of $domain part in the URL

Comment: Maybe you can define env variables via VirtualHost settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution, it was in my controller all along.

I created a new function called getDomain:

```
public function getDomain(){
    $domain = Domain::model()->find('domain_name=:domain_name', array(':domain_name'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl));
    return $domain->domain_name;
}
```

then inside my actionView function

```
public function actionView($domain = null,$page = null, $parm = null){
    if ($domain === null){
        $domain = $this->getDomain();
    } ...
```

Now it works with out the $domain having to be inside the URL

Answer (score 1):

what about defining new action in your siteController, or find a way using actionIndex, to get both domain and page as input and render the corresponding domain, page from DB.